# I have a button in my Flutter project that I want the phone number to appear when pressed by the user

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I have a **button** in my Flutter project that I want the **phone number** to appear when it's pressed by the user, and when the number appears, the user can **copy the number** and use it, or when pressing the button, it goes to a **direct call process** with the phone number

Is there a way or a widget by which I can achieve this?

Comment: you can use GestureDetector to achieve multiple gestures on one button widget and you can use the services package for handling copying to the clipboard, include a snippet of your code, and I will help

Comment: Thank you, I will try to use the way you mentioned and if it doesn't work I will post the code for help

Comment: could you add your code? @kareemAlhoni

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [URL launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) in every where you want, like this:

```dart
Center(
  child: TextButton(
      onPressed: () => launch("tel://21213123123"),
      child: Text("Call me")),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) to direct call process with the phone number,
or send sms as you want